# Create Button with vanilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I need the following button created in vanilla javascript:

```
<button class="etmkug-14 SuUwW">
    <span class="etmkug-16 ctwFJG">Mark All Read</span>
</button>
```

Not sure about how to create and add the span:

```
var button = document.createElement('button');
button.setAttribute('class','etmkug-14 SuUwW');
button.setAttribute('style','margin-left: 10px;');
button.setAttribute('id','mark-all-read');
button.addEventListener('click', function(event){
    .
    .
    .
}
var span = document.createElement('span');
span.setAttribute('class','etmkug-16 ctwFJG');
span.innerHTML = 'Mark All Read';
button.appendChild(span);                // Is this how it's done????
```

Comment: Looks right to me. Have you tested it?

Comment: You have working code that you just needed to try

Comment: Actually, haven't had time to test it, yet...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes that is how it is done. You just need to add this line `document.body.append(button);`

```js
var button = document.createElement('button');
button.setAttribute('class','etmkug-14 SuUwW');
button.setAttribute('style','margin-left: 10px;');
button.setAttribute('id','mark-all-read');
var span = document.createElement('span');
span.setAttribute('class','etmkug-16 ctwFJG');
span.innerHTML = 'Mark All Read';
button.appendChild(span);    
document.body.append(button);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're feeling lazy InnerHTML is your friend; Grab a container and append some HTML.

```
var container = document.getElementById('container');
container.innerHTML = container.innerHTML + '<button class="etmkug-14 SuUwW"><span class="etmkug-16 ctwFJG">Mark All Read</span></button>';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let newButton = document.createElement('button');
newButton.setAttribute("id", "myNewButton");
newButton.className = "myClassName";
newButton.innerText = "clickMe";
newButton.addEventListener("click", clickMe);
document.body.appendChild(newButton);
function clickMe(){
    console.log("Hi! I  am a new Button.");
}
```

Comment: What is the improvement as compared with accepted Answer?